# Custom textfield in Material-UI select

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, material-ui

this is an example from Material-UI select that we can pick an age for the user

https://i.stack.imgur.com/23cec.png
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/

Do you know how we can add a custom TextField at the end where user can write any number into?

For example, in this case we write in Fourty.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aF9Zg.png

After that, "Fourty", even though not an predefined option, will be displayed in the dropdown here.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IB5eX.png

I have tried add TextField inside a MenuItem with value as a state but the dropdown doesn't display the value from the TextField.

Comment: What are you looking to do? Add a new option if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes, it's not search. So we would like to pick a few of the existing options, or add a totally new option.

Comment: As per your screenshot, the component you're using is an MUI Autocomplete, if all that you're looking to do is add new option when it doesn't exist, while being able to search for it, you can use [creatable variant](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#creatable) of Autocomplete, else, if you're looking to have a text field like you have in your screenshot, you should use MUI Select. I can provide you with a code sample for Select, the Autocomplete sample can be copied from the docs. I'll write up an answer if you need an MUI Select.

Comment: Actually, I figured it out how to do it. Thanks everyone! I would use Select multiple/chip and override default action from MUI Select.